# Way to find what stored procedure/script is behind SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I have read access to the `tables`, `stored procedures`, and `functions` from a `sql server` database. I can also view the generated SSRS report from a browser. I just don't have access to the actual SSRS report.

Is there a way to know what stored procedure or tsql script is run when a report is generated?

Thanks.

Comment: Not without the .rdl file. In Report Manager you can just see the data source.

Comment: one way of doing it is to have sql profiler running and use that to try to capture the calls made by your rdl.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a particular account that is utilized to run the report, you can utilize the MSSQL activity monitor from the management studio and see the view/query that is run from there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any way to find which stored procedure is calling behind SSRS Report without `.RDL` file of that SSRS report.

If you have access of database then you can check using [SQL Server Profiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/). Also, to check this log you must have administrator credentials.